# How to upload a directory recursively to an FTP server by just using ftp or lftp?

Tags: ftp, directory, synchronization, upload, recursive

I am writing a Linux shell script to copy a local directory to a remote server (removing any existing files).

**Local server:** `ftp` and `lftp` commands are available, **no** `ncftp` or any graphical tools.

**Remote server:** only accessible via FTP. No rsync nor SSH nor FXP.

I am thinking about listing local and remote files to generate a lftp script and then run it. Is there a better way?

*Note: Uploading only modified files would be a plus, but not required.*

Comment: ncftp is totally out the question ? Would be easiest imho. (and i know it'll do it as i use it that way)

Comment: Sirex: I would rather do it with tools that come by default on RedHat. If lftp proves unusable, I will add a requirement for users to install ncftp.

Comment: The syntax for `wput` (a wget-like ftp-uploader): `wput dir/ ftp://user:pass@host/dir`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) should be able to do this in one step, in particular with `lftp mirror`:

The lftp command syntax is confusing, original invocation I posted doesn't work.  Try it like this:

> lftp -e "mirror -R {local dir} {remote dir}" -u {username},{password} {host}

**note** the quotes around the arguments to the `-e` switch.

Comment: +1 for tipping me that lftp's mirror mode works even if FXP is not available (I was convinced of the opposite after reading http://tutorials.papamike.ca/pub/lftp.html which says "both servers must support this protocol for this operation to succeed"). However, this particular command fails on my Ubuntu server: lftp: mirror: Name or service not known, Unknown command `-R'.

Comment: I reworded my answer with a better invocation of lftp, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I finally gt it to work! It seems that you must switch remote and local for it to work. Please update and I will accept this answer. Here is a command line that works: lftp -e "mirror -R /tmp/mylocalfiles /var/www" -u remoteuser,remotepassword remoteserver

Comment: I think I saw in the lftp docs that you had to switch the local and remote dirs when using -R but I must have forgot.  Updated my answer.

Comment: How does it fail? Have you tried running 'lftp -vvv' for more verbose output to determine what it's trying to do?

Comment: lftp -c "open -u {username},{password} {host}; mirror -R {local dir} {remote dir}"

Comment: add `--parallel=10` after `-R`  to speed things up

Comment: Thanks! Uploading my data onto NCBI GEO's server now using this command:
`lftp -e "mirror -R Mydirectory/ uploads/NCBIGEOdirectory/" -u geoftp,TheirPassword ftp-private.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov`

Answer (score 4):

```
cd {local_dir}
lftp {server}
cd {remote_dir}
mput {local_dir}/*
```

This worked for me, many other attempts were failing. Once in lftp, more info available via:

```
help mput
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use `mirror -R` here.

Comment: @gauteh you're right. best answer ^

Answer (score 1):

Based on Phil's idea of using lftp's mirror mode, this command does the trick:

```
lftp -c 'open -e "mirror /tmp/thedir ftp://nico:mypass@remotehost/~/destination/" ftp://nico:mypass@localhost'
```

A drawback is that it requires the local server to have an FTP server running.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the common answer of using mirroring, I often find it preferable to use `mput`, especially if there are several directories to transfer.

For example, given the following:

```
lftp> !ls
mydir1
mydir2
mydir3
mydir4
mydir5
```

... if the goal is to transfer directories `mydir[2-4]`, you can either clunkily use the `mirror` command:

```
lftp mirror -R mydir2 mydir2
```

... and repeat serially for `mydir3` and `mydir4`... or you can use `mput` as follows:

```
lftp> mput -d mydir[2-4]/*
```

... and be done.  The `-d` option is key here:

```
lftp> help mput
Usage: mput [OPTS] <files>
Upload files with wildcard expansion
...
 -d  create directories the same as in file names and put the
     files into them instead of current directory
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer!!!
Create shell script ftpmirror.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
path = /local-dir-path
lftp -e "mirror -R $path /$path" -u username,password ftp-server-ip
```

- Path = local directory which we want to copy into ftp server
- username = ftp server user name
- password = ftp server password
- ftp-server-ip = IP address of ftp server

If lftp package is not installed the installed it using yum.